# Curl errno=6 after about a day of work

Tags: php, curl, nginx

Two days ago I've noticed that our servers (nginx + php-fpm) stopped working because curl function start return CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST. After reboot everyting become working again. But now, after about a day of work, I've noticed the same error.

When I ssh to a server `$ wget http://example.com` is working. I can also request *http://example.com* from php running as cli. But when I try to curl *http://example.com* from php in web server I get CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST.

I made reboot again and it is working now... But I think that tomorrow I will have to made another reboot.

Any ideas about root cause?

Comment: i have the same issue, if you've `curled` using shell curl lib every thing will be ok, this happens only if you using libcurl from php, however i'm still looking for a solution;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956679/wordpress-wp-remote-post-gives-curl-error-6-could-not-resolve-host/42957214#42957214

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Ubuntu by any chance?

Ubuntu pushed an update a short time ago to revert the changes they made in yesterday's update which broke the services and required a restart all PHP-FPM processes

https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3239-2/

Comment: Yes, we are using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. But we did'nt install any updates. After ssh I can see the following message `141 packages can be updated. 20 updates are security updates.`. Will try to do upgrade tomorrow.