# Wordpress wp_remote_post() gives "cURL error 6: Could not resolve host"

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, dns

Since this morning some function in a wordpress site I'm managing is not working anymore. I syslogged the response from it, which gives me:

```
{"errors":{"http_request_failed":["cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: subdomain.example.com"]},"error_data":[]}
```

When I manually run curl from that machine I simply get the html as a response. Since it says it could not resolve the host, I presume the problem occurs before the domain name can be resolved to an ip. So I guess (but not sure) this has something to do with the DNS.

I really don't understand what could be wrong here or how I can debug this. Does anybody have a suggestion?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42948344/curl-errno-6-after-about-a-day-of-work

Comment: @hassan - Thanks! I rebooted and now it works again. If you add your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: i don't know if the reboot is the right solution, i'm not a pro server admin , i just faced it in my own server, i think the right solution by following this instructions https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Upgrades , restarting nginx and php-fpm will solve the issue temporarily , so i think rebooting the system maybe the same;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as mentioned [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Upgrades) and due to this [USN](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3239-2/):

you will may need to update your dist

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

this fixed my issue with curl

---

### Update

you will need to be aware of the dist-upgrade step, some packages -*such as php*- during the updrage will prompt you to ask you wether you want to replace the configuration files , you must be very aware of what you are doing here , keeping those files or replacing with the new -default- files.