# Hack attempt causing nginx crash

Tags: php, node.js, security, nginx

Every two days my server for the past week, hosted on AWS ElasticBeanstalk, has been crashing. Looking through the logs I see the following shortly before the server becomes inaccessible:

**nginx access logs**

```
139.162.124.167 - - [22/Mar/2017:09:54:05 +0000] "GET http://clientapi.ipip.net/echo.php?info=20170322175406 HTTP/1.1" 404 977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64)" "-"
139.162.124.167 - - [22/Mar/2017:09:54:05 +0000] "\x05\x02\x00\x02" 400 173 "-" "-" "-"
139.162.124.167 - - [22/Mar/2017:09:54:05 +0000] "\x05\x02\x00\x02" 400 173 "-" "-" "-"
```

**node.js logs**

`GET /echo.php?info=20170322175406`

My guess is what is happening is they are verifying an active server accepting requests and then dumping the characters (from the following exploit: http://downloads.securityfocus.com/vulnerabilities/exploits/34291.c) onto the open TCP/IP connection which causes it to crash/stop responding.

I've recently added better exception logging to the node instance, but until it happens again are there any other steps I can take to prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956679/wordpress-wp-remote-post-gives-curl-error-6-could-not-resolve-host/

Answer (score 1):

Found this payload [here](https://github.com/lnxg33k/misc/blob/master/shellshock.py), which is a [shock attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)).  This is about the worst thing that can happen to you -- attacker gets a shell on your nginx box, then from there has access to your internal network (which is far worse than the crashing that you experienced).  Who knows how much further he has penetrated.  Is your TLS private key on the nginx box?  If so, attacker should have gotten access to it.

The #1 thing you need to do is upgrade to the latest version of nginx.  You should then change your passwords on the nginx box, and inspect all your other internal systems that are accessible from the nginx box.

Comment: I came across that as well. What's interesting is that this is a single box on AWS ElasticBeanstalk using the most recent version of software that Amazon provides. There isn't an option to upgrade nginx any further. For now I've updated to Apache. This machine also didn't have SSL certs (it was a dev box) and had no access to any authentication/databases. It was mostly hitting public APIs and visualizing them.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your nginx on the server until it doesn't crash any more.

The nginx should never crash on any request. If the latest versions still crashes then see if that issue has already been reported. If it has not then report the issue yourself. If it has then track the discussion and see when it will be resolved.

The chances are that you may be using an outdated version of nginx and simply upgrading it will resolve the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956679/wordpress-wp-remote-post-gives-curl-error-6-could-not-resolve-host/

Comment: This is the default nginx config on AWS ElasticBeanstalk, which has no ability to be upgraded which leads me to believe that this should be more widespread.