# DNS resolution stops working with Apache2.4.7/PHP5.5.9 until restart

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, dns, linode

I have a problem that has just started over the last few days. The server has been running and working great for over two years.

In my PHP application, I connect to S3 and Sendgrid. This week I've started getting the following errors:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.sendgrid.net [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname #0]

DNS works fine on the command line and it works in the app after I restart Apache.

I restarted Apache yesterday but we started getting errors again today. Nothing had changed, no restarts or anything. There is nothing in the Apache error log to indicate anything has happened.

Server Details:

- Linode 1024 VPS
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Apache 2.4.7
- PHP 5.5.9

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956679/wordpress-wp-remote-post-gives-curl-error-6-could-not-resolve-host/42957214#42957214

Comment: Only packages that updated were datadog-agent, git, and git-man

Comment: it's not about the updated packages, it's about the packages which you have to update;

Comment: I don't see anything else to update. I reread the thread you pointed me to and I'm already running Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.11. Just to be on the safe side I rebooted the server and I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: uhmm I don't know but after updating my dist , `apt-get dist-upgrade` it works fine with me until now